# Android can't play a wav file in my res/raw folder

Tags: android

I'm building an android app.  And I just want to play a wav file if it exists in my /res/raw folder.  The following code does not work because the f.exists() always evaluates to false:

```
    String filePathString = "android.resource://"+_context.getPackageName()+"/res/raw/oldphone_mono.wav";
    File f = new File(filePathString);

    java.io.InputStream inputStream = _context.getResources().openRawResource(com.hello20.R.raw.oldphone_mono);


    if(f.exists()) {

        Uri ringUri = Uri.parse(filePathString);

        _ring = new MediaPlayer();
        _ring.setDataSource(_context, ringUri);

        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
            _ring.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            _ring.setLooping(true);
            _ring.prepare();
            _ring.start();
        }
```

What else should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load wav by other way:

```
 _ring=MediaPlayer.create(_context,R.raw.oldphone_mono);
 _ring.start();
 _ring.setLooping( true );
```

*Comment 1*

You don't need in my case to use `_ring.prepare();`. `MediaPlayer.create` takes care about

*Comment 2*

Further, since you load wav resource from raw, you don't need `if(f.exists())` statemant